# Lower Response for ASP.net core web API 2+ when compared to .net framework4+

Tags: performance, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-framework-version

As a part of Azure transition ,we are evaluating our current web api projects [4.5.1] for .net core web api 2+ conversion. When tested on Dev machine Windows 10] IIS Express and postman ,the default templates endpoint which returns just two strings[Value1,Value2] ,takes ~40 ns in .net core where as it is just ~5 to 10 ns in .net framework. Only for the first request .net framework is taking ~150 ns after that it is always around 5 to 10 ns

We observed the same behavior after converting an existing asp.net web api framework.4.5.1 to .net core api 2.0 ....net Core is ~5 times slower than .net framework [in subsequent requests]!!!!!

Also .net framework process bitness is showing as 32

```
public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            var processBitness = Environment.Is64BitProcess;
            var osBitness = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem;
            return new[]
            {
                "value:",  "processBitness" + processBitness, "osBitness" + osBitness
            };
        }
}
```

As mentioned every where .net core is faster than .net framework,so I would expect the default template web api [core]endpoint  with no functionality would at least respond faster than the web api endpoint[framework]..

Comment: do not use IIS express for this, run the comparison against a proper IIS instance

Comment: I have tried the basic templates [dotnet framework api ,dotnet core api] in IIS7 and Azure App Service. dotnet framework api takes ~5ms and core api takes ~40.Note:[Within Core :For in process and outprocess there is minor performance boost]